# Regex: match all hyphens and replace by spaces for words that contains only letters AND that are NOT inside quotes

Tags: java, regex, clojure

This regex: `\b([A-z*]+)-(?=[A-z*]+\b)`

with this replacement: `$1`

Applied on:

```
Jean-Pierre bought "blue-green-red" product-2345 and other blue-red stuff.
```

Gives me:

```
Jean Pierre bought "blue green red" product-2345 and other blue red stuff.
```

While I want:

```
Jean Pierre bought "blue-green-red" product-2345 and other blue red stuff.
```

https://regex101.com/r/SJzAaP/1

EDIT:

I am using Clojure (Java)

EDIT 2:

`yellow-black-white` -> `yellow black white`

`product_a-b` -> `product_a-b`

EDIT 3: Accepted answer translated in Clojure

```
(clojure.string/replace
 "Jean-Pierre bought \"blue-green-red\" product-2345 and other blue-red-green stuff yellow-black-white product_a-b"
 #"(\"[^\"]*\")|\b([a-zA-Z]+)-(?=[a-zA-Z]+\b)"
 (fn [[s1 s2 s3]] (if s2 s1 (str s3 " "))))

;;=> "Jean Pierre bought \"blue-green-red\" product-2345 and other blue red green stuff yellow black white product_a-b"
```

Comment: Your regex [does not match that string](https://regex101.com/r/HwR9cI/1).

Comment: This is actually my best shot: https://regex101.com/r/SJzAaP/1 Just edited question. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, just FYI: `[A-z]` does [not only match letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926). What is your regex flavor?

Comment: Thanks again, edited the title.

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand your question :-)

Comment: Use  `"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(?!)|\b[a-zA-Z]+\K-(?=[a-zA-Z]+\b)`  and replace with a space. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SJzAaP/2).

Comment: True. How about Java compatible without `(*SKIP)` or `\K` ? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to actual Java code?

Comment: I have access to clojure code, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  Java, you may use something like

```
String s = "Jean-Pierre bought \"blue-green-red\" product-2345 and other blue-red stuff. yellow-black-white. product_a-b";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]*\")|\\b([a-zA-Z]+)-(?=[a-zA-Z]+\\b)").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(0));
    } else {
        m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(2) + " ");
    }
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
// => Jean Pierre bought "blue-green-red" product-2345 and other blue red stuff. yellow black white. product_a-b
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/LJbbk6).

The regex is

```
("[^"]*")|\b([a-zA-Z]+)-(?=[a-zA-Z]+\b)
```

**Details**

- `("[^"]*")` - Group 1: `"`, 0+ chars other than `"` and `"`
- `|` - or
- `\b` - word boundary
  -`([a-zA-Z]+)` - Group 2: 1+ letters (may be replaced with `(\p{L}+)` to match any letter)
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=[a-zA-Z]+\b)` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, requires 1+ letters and a word boundary.

If Group 1 matches (`if (m.group(1) != null)`) you just paste the match back into the result. If not, paste back Group 2 value and a space.

Adding [clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure) code here from the question, too, for better visibility:

```
(def s "Jean-Pierre bought \"blue-green-red\" product-2345 and other blue-red stuff. yellow-black-white. product_a-b"

(defn append [[g1 g2 g3]] (if g2 g1 (str g3 " ")))

(clojure.string/replace s #"(\"[^\"]*\")|\b([a-zA-Z]+)-(?=[a-zA-Z]+\b)" append)

;;=> "Jean Pierre bought \"blue-green-red\" product-2345 and other blue red stuff. yellow black white. product_a-b"
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine! Translated your answer in Clojure in my last question edit.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you don't need to handle too complex cases:

`(?: |^)\w+(-)(?![0-9])\w+`

This matches any instance of `word(hyphen)word` that has a space at the beginning or is the beginning of the line (so, the stuff in the quotes will not match because there would be a quote before it, not a space or the beginning of the line).

Let me know if this doesn't work for you. [Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/UDYcVM/1).

Comment: Hmm, that's working except wouldn't work for `other blue-red-green-yellow stuff` which I want to cover too and I don't want this removed `product_a-b`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
(".*?")|((?<group>\b([A-z*]+))-)
```

with substitution

```
${group} $1
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/jmfqCz/1)

Comment: `bought  "blue-green-red" product 2345` should be `bought "blue-green-red" product-2345`